# Sparx EA. How to merge files from work of multiple architects

Tags: merge, model, enterprise-architect

I am using Sparx EA for developing architectural models. We are a 2 member team located in different states of the US. 
I have set up a DBMS MySql on the cloud.
I am able to connect to the DBMS and do a project transfer of .eap file.
My Question is
1. How do me my colleague work on the same file and put it in DBMS repository without overwriting each others work.
2. Do I need a SVN or some version control to load the files in versio control and then transfer from version control to DBMS?

Could somebody explain the steps to acheive this.

Thanks
Ramani

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways you could approach this.

1. If your colleagues are disconnection from the web:
   Create your main repository on the the cloud 
   Do an xmi export with baseline
   Send that to each of your colleges, when they are finished they can send back their new xmi with the merge file:

See here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/12/index.html#xmimerge

2. (recommended) If your all web enabled
   Create your repository using the sparx cloud service.
   Each member connects to it regardless of where they are in the world (with all the network optimizations turned on)
   Use EA's internal project management features (like locking, auditing, baselining etc) to not step on each others toes.

See here for a guide - look up Deployment options, Multi-site Cloud Service : http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/whitepapers/EA_Deployment.pdf